# Список файлов в shell unix.

Tags: unix, shell

Нужно написать Shell программу, которая считает количество каталогов и выводит список  всех файлов без папок в порядку уменьшения их длинны в поддереве, начиная с папки, которая дается как входной параметр.
    Выводить надо в форме дерева.

каталог <имя папки>(начальный каталог)

- <имя файла><длинна>
- <имя файла><длинна>
- ...

каталог <имя папки>(подпапка)

- <имя файла><длинна>
- <имя файла><длинна>
- ...

Comment: Пример ввода и вывода приведите, пожалуйста. Очень невнятное описание получилось.

Comment: find, ls, wc Вам в помощь. man-ы читайте.

Comment: @gecube добавил описание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так наверное

```
ls -lsSR <имя папки>(начальный каталог)
```

всё и покажет

или более компактно

```
ls -shSR <имя папки>(начальный каталог)
```